# Substitute multiple spaces with character during SELECT

Tags: sql, substitution

I have some field values that contain 5 spaces as a separator e.g.

> `AWERDC     123`

I do a weekly extract that ends up being submitted to an outside party, but any of these particular values need to have a '#' substituted (`AWERDC#123`).  I am looking for the best way to do the transform during the SELECT.

What can I do?

Comment: Is it always exactly 5 spaces, or is it up to 5 spaces? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: The answer is DBMS dependent, for example in TSQL you can use `replace`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, and if there are always 5 spaces, you can use `replace()`, like this example:

```
declare @s varchar(100) = 'AWERDC     123'

select replace(@s, '     ', '#')
```

Which returns:

```
AWERDC#123
```

If there are a variable number of spaces, then you can handle that using `stuff()`, `charindex()` and `patindex()`.  This example depends on the characters before the variable number of spaces to be letters, and the characters after the spaces to be numbers.  If your data is otherwise, you will have to modify the `patindex()` accordingly.

```
declare @s varchar(100) = 'AWERDC       123'

select stuff(@s, charindex(' ', @s, 1), patindex('%[0-9]%', @s) - charindex(' ', @s, 1), '#')
```

Which always returns `AWERDC#123`, regardless of how many spaces there are.

Here is an improved approach that doesn't care what type of characters are in the leading and trailing characters.  It simply works with a variable number of spaces, because it searches for the first space forward, then the first space backwards (in the string), does the math, then inserts a single `#` in place of all the spaces using `stuff()`:

```
declare @s varchar(100) = 'AWERDC             123'

select stuff(@s, charindex(' ', @s, 1), len(@s) - charindex(' ', reverse(@s), 1) - charindex(' ', @s, 1) + 2, '#')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a simple Replace in your query.

```
SELECT REPLACE([Column], '     ','#') From [dbo.Table]
```